# Create a new Jenkins job automatically when a new github repository is created

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, system-administration

I search a manner to Create a new Jenkins job automatically when a new github repository is created.

I use auto-job plugin for automatically creating Jenkins jobs from scm branche but it's not work when I create a repository.

Any plug-in exist for that ? I found nothing for that ...

thank you in advance

Comment: Nobody Knows ? I really need tips

Comment: Have you looked at the [Organization folder plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-organization-folder-plugin#github-organization-folder)?

Comment: @osowskit thanks lot ! it's exactly what i search !!!!!!!